# How can I automate Chocolatey install from a private Azure DevOps hosted feed?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I've got a Chocolatey package hosted in a private Azure Devops feed. The feed requires authentication. I'm trying to run this from a PowerShell script in a build task.

`choco install typewriter --source="https://o365x.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Graph/nuget/v3/index.json" --yes --force --password=PAT`

I observe that it attempts basic auth. Alternate credentials are disabled for my org. I tried to use a personal access token as the password (no username) and it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps feeds are v3, but Chocolatey only supports v2.

You should try replacing /v3/index.json in the source with /v2, e.g. in your case:

https://o365x.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Graph/nuget/v2

Microsoft has actually documented that (for nuget) in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=azure-devops#add-a-feed-to-nuget-2